# php artisan migrate command generate data in multiple schema's

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

i am working on multi-tenancy. I have multiple schema's in single db. for example PostgreSQL db has public,private1,private2 schema's. I want to run migration in all schema's by running "php artisan migrate"

Comment: You cannot do that, php artisan migrate will only work for default DB engine provided in the database.php.

Comment: what about Laravel PGSchema ?

Comment: I think it is a promising solution, have you tried it?

Comment: not yet. i think its for  Laravel 4.1

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: currently Laravel 4.2

Comment: Okay, that package is not stable for 4.2, but works fine with 4.1.